# WebScraping with HTML Unit Issue with apache lang3

Tags: java, web, web-crawler, htmlunit

UPDATE: I ended up using ghost.py but would appreciate a response.

I have been using straight java/apache httpd and nio to crawl must pages recently but came across what I expected was a simple issue that actually appears to not be. I am trying to use html unit to crawl a page but every time I run the code below I get the error proceeding the code telling me a jar is missing. Unfortunately, I could not find my answer here as there is a weird part to this question.

So, here is the weird part. I have the jar (lang3) it is up to date and it contains a method StringUtils.startsWithIgnoreCase(String string,String prefix) that works. I would really like to avoid selenium as I need to crawl (if sampling tells me properly), about 1000 pages on the same site over several months.

Is there a particular version I need? All I saw was the note to update to 3-1 which I have. Is there a method if installation that works?

Thanks.

The code I am running is:

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;

import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.BrowserVersion;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.FailingHttpStatusCodeException;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.Page;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.RefreshHandler;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlAnchor;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlForm;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlPage;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTable;
import com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.html.HtmlTableRow;


public class crawl {

public crawl()
{
    //TODO Constructor
    crawl_page();
}


public void crawl_page()
{
    //TODO control the crawling 



    WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.FIREFOX_10);

    webClient.setRefreshHandler(new RefreshHandler() {
        public void handleRefresh(Page page, URL url, int arg) throws IOException {
            System.out.println("handleRefresh");
        }

    });

        //the url for CA's Megan's law sex off
        String url="http://www.myurl.com" //not my url

        HtmlPage page;
        try {
            page = (HtmlPage) webClient.getPage(url);
            HtmlForm form=page.getFormByName("_ctl0");
            form.getInputByName("cbAgree").setChecked(true);

            page=form.getButtonByName("Continue").click();

            System.out.println(page.asText());


        } catch (FailingHttpStatusCodeException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }




}
```

}

The error is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:      org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.startsWithIgnoreCase(Ljava/lang/CharSequence;Ljava/lang/CharSequence;)Z
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.util.URLCreator$URLCreatorStandard.toUrlUnsafeClassic(URLCreator.java:66)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.util.UrlUtils.toUrlUnsafe(UrlUtils.java:193)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.util.UrlUtils.toUrlSafe(UrlUtils.java:171)
at com.gargoylesoftware.htmlunit.WebClient.<clinit>(WebClient.java:159)
at ca__soc.crawl.crawl_page(crawl.java:34)
at ca__soc.crawl.<init>(crawl.java:24)
at ca__soc.us_ca_ca_soc.main(us_ca_ca_soc.java:17)
```

Comment: just a hint, stick to java naming convention. Lowercase class cause tilt on my brain(probably not the only one).

Comment: What version of HtmlUnit you are using?

Comment: I am using html unit version 2.12 and have only one jar. As for the naming convention, sorry about that. I will change it next time. I just don't have the ability to choose which one I can use. Complete flub on my part.

Comment: Use the default, it's make easier to read your code, and understand others: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconv-138413.html

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringUtils.html#startsWithIgnoreCase%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)

> Since:
>     2.4, 3.0 Changed signature from startsWithIgnoreCase(String, String) to startsWithIgnoreCase(CharSequence, CharSequence)

so, probably you have two similar jars on your classpath.

Comment: weird, I only have lang3 3.1 (1 copy) and the javadoc says exactly what you documented but I still cannot access it. I am trying in eclipse and rebuilt my project java library. Could it be the IDE? It finds the class path but not the proper method despite what the javadoc says.

Comment: Try printing your classpath: http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-print-out-the-current-project-classpath/